# What are the Different types of dimensions in SSAS

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssas, ssas-2008

I am learning SSAS now. In that I heard that there are many types of dimensions. What are those types. Like parent-child there are some more categories.
Can any one explain.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Types of Dimensions:

Snow flake dimensions :  Based on more than one source table.
Degenerate dimensions : Based on column in fact table.
This dimension will increase the size of the fact table.
Use only based on the business requirements, not much useful.

Parent-child dimensions :  Based on self referencing relation ship. 
Example : Employee table. It has EmpID, MangerID.
This is treating as regular dimension from SSAS 2005
Many-Many dimensions : Atleast having three source tables.
Eg : Courses, Instructor tables
This solved the modelling problems in SSAS 2000

Role playing dimensions : Based on multiple relation ships with single table.
Eg: Time dimension. in that we have OrderData,ShippingDate, DeliveryDate etc.
Often used with Time Dimension

Write back dimensions : Primitive end users to update the source data.
This can be used by setting write back property to true. In properties pane we have option as WriteEnabled. By default it is set to false. Mark it as true.
Simple to implement by dangerous because data is modified.

Mining Model : Based on the mining structure you defined.